# How to query deleted contacts

Tags: query, undelete

This bozo (me) managed to delete some contacts that shouldn't be deleted with a list of those that should.

Now the whole world knows about it and is waiting for me to restore them.

I do this query below and get 0 results but I see at least on the the recycle bin. Why and how to fix this? I know the date and time when I did this if that helps.

SELECT Id, name, IsDeleted FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ALL ROWS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm)

> You can use ALL ROWS to query records in your organization's Recycle Bin.

So your query needs to be:

```
SELECT Id, name, IsDeleted FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE ALL ROWS
```

Comment: I tried this SELECT Id, name, IsDeleted FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted = True ALL ROWS in workbench and in the developer console query and get the error MALFORMED_QUERY: ALL ROWS not allowed in this context or Parsing Error

Comment: Try using the Dev. Console. instead. This query definitely works for me in the console, not sure why it's not working in Workbench though.

Comment: Thanks but I wrote, I tried both exactly as I pasted above. Am I supposed to type it differently.

Comment: This runs successfully for me: 

system.debug([SELECT Id, name, IsDeleted FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted = True ALL ROWS]);

Try that.

Comment: Davin your too helpful. Not that the query works. Is there a way to filter the day/time I deleted the records. Right now I get over 1,000 as isdeleted. I know when i deleted it more or less

Comment: Yes you can filter by date / datetime: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Filter by LastModifiedDate I guess in your case.

Comment: You did it. I need to work on it but I should be able to restore humpy dumpdy.  Many thanks.

Comment: This does not work in a SOQL query

Answer (score 0):

I hope You have gone through
[Retrieve Lost Records](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-retrieve-my-records-and-data-that-has-been-lost-or-deleted-1327108681812&language=en_US)

```
SELECT Id, name, IsDeleted FROM Contact WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE ALL ROWS
```

Comment: How is that different from my answer?

Comment: I dont know how it happened. I had written the same